# Pause and reset HTML audio

Tags: jquery, html

I want to pause all audio elements on my page and reset the **currentTime** to 0.

When I loop through the jquery elements I'm getting error `a.pause is not a function` and `Cannot create property 'currentTime' on number '0'`

```
var audio = $('audio')
audio.each((a) => {
  a.pause()    
  a.currentTime = 0
})
```

Comment: _"Do I have to loop through all the audio elements if I have more than 1?"_ Why don't you just try it and see?

Comment: I tried to do `audio.forEach((a) => { a.currentTime = 0 }` but I got an error `audio.forEach is not a function`

Comment: You made `audio` a jQuery object so use `.each()`

Comment: Now I'm getting error `Cannot create property 'currentTime' on number '0'`

Comment: And `a.pause is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at the [official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/) of `.each`.

To summarize, the first argument of `.each` is the index of the audio element and the second one is the audio element itself, so the solution would be:

```
var audios = $('audio')
audios.each((i, a) => {
  a.pause()    
  a.currentTime = 0
});
```